# Artifacts/Specs in viewport and rendered output

Tags: rendering, artifacts

I have an issue where black specs are not just in the viewport, but also get rendered out. System specs or given below. Is this caused by drivers, hardware, or settings in blender? I have tried installing the NVIDIA driver for the card, but the system always crashes. The system does not know the model of the GPU when running lshw or going into additional drivers. The specs that appear do not move even when i rotate the view. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

SYSTEM SPECS --[image]
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
CPU: Ryzen 9 3950
RAM: 32GB
GPU: Zotac Nvidia GTX 3070
Display Driver: Nouveau

Comment: What is this image illustrating? I don't see any specs

Comment: Are you sure you don't just have to clean your monitor?

Comment: I just uploaded it without opening it after saving the image. I just noticed that the specs are not there myself when looking at the image in the post. They are, however, there in the rendered image and in the viewport. Real smart Steinmetz.